# api result not displaying in index.ejs but console log works in index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

i'm trying to add an api to a project and ive gotten the index.js to console log the result and it works well but , i can not seem to understand how to display on my index.ejs

```js
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const urlAndKey = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=7160918468a64df9a7bf26e5915c1f50";


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.ejs", { content: "Your news will display here." });
});



  app.get("/apiKey", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get(urlAndKey);
      console.log(result.data);
      res.render("index.ejs", { content: result.data });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).send(error.message);
    }
  });


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
  });
```

```ejs
<div class="container col-7">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    <a href="/apiKey" class="btn btn-primary pill-rounded">Get All The NEWs</a> </div>
 


    
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
    <%if (locals.content) {%><div class="img-fluid text-center mt-5">
     <textarea  style="border: black; border-style: solid; width:530px; height:150px ;margin-top: 10px;" readonly>
<%= content %>
        </textarea>
       </div>
        <%}%>
    </div></div>
```

i am trying to display the news articles to the text area of the ejs file i have tried content.articles.titles , <%= content %> and a few more ,i can't figure out what i'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can modify your code:

Create a new EJS template called "news.ejs":

```
<!-- news.ejs -->
<div class="container col-7">
    <div class="row">
        <% for (const article of content.articles) { %>
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
                <p><%= article.description %></p>
                <a href="<%= article.url %>" target="_blank">Read More</a>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modify your server code to render the "news.ejs" template when fetching news data:

```
// Server code
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const apiKey = "YOUR_NEWS_API_KEY"; // Replace with your actual API key

app.set("view engine", "ejs"); // Set EJS as the view engine
app.use(express.static("public")); // Serve static assets from the "public" folder

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.render("index.ejs");
});

app.get("/news", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&apiKey=${apiKey}`;
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const newsData = response.data;
    res.render("news.ejs", { content: newsData });
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
}
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Modify your index.ejs to include a link to the "/news" route:

```
<!-- index.ejs -->
<div class="container col-7">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <a href="/news" class="btn btn-primary pill-rounded">Get All The News</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```